# Upload a file using Http connection and calculating percentage of uploaded bytes

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I want to upload a file to the server using the HttpConnection. So I want to make a GaugeField representing the percentage of uploading job.

But all that I can find in OutputStream is `.flush()` which will flush the entire Output Stream once to the server. So I am not able to calculate the bytes uploaded at a specific time

How to make that? Any idea?

I used the following but it is giving error most of the time:

```
           while (position < length) {
                try {
                    os.write(postDataBytes, position, length100);
                    position += length100;
                    int location = position * 100 / length;
                    gaugeField.setValue(location);
                    os.flush();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Send 1M at a time (or some other suitable increment), and update the percentage after each send.

Comment: @DavidWallace How to make that? I updated my question on how I used it but this gives failure most of the time ... So I used it in a wrong way I guess

Comment: The basic idea looks roughly right.  What do you mean when you say it "gives failure most of the time"?  Exactly what happens?  And what is length100 in your code - where has that come from?

Comment: @DavidWallace length100 depends every time on the size of the file. The exception is : RuntimeException Stream already closed.
That means that the flush method on EDGE and 3G is closing the OutputStream

Answer (score 2):

**There are two ways to do that:**

- **Client Side :** Identify the bytes which client has written (Which is not the right way because you will not be knowing if the data has actually reached the server or not) . In this case, you should be counting the bytes written by providing you custom SocketFactory and wrapping the underlying socket.
- **Server Side :** The best way is to keep the count of the data read by server in a session and let the client make requests to know the upload progress.

**Here are the steps to achieve this:**

1) In the Upload Servlet on the server side update the read bytes in the session.

```
 session.setAttribute(pBytesRead);
```

2) Write a servlet UploadProgressServlet  which writes the progress to the response.

```
response.getOutputStream().write(session.getAttribute("uploadprogress"));
```

3) Let the client make requests to UploadProgressServlet to know the progress

You can also Use [Apache Commons Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) API which has Progress Listener support. In this case you have to write the data in multipart format.

Comment: Do you have an example on how does this work in real Blackberry code?

Comment: From where do I get the libraries? No such code is recognized in the JDE

Comment: I have updated the answer, can u look at it. Ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: But I cant make requests to know the total size upload each time I want to update the GaugeField. I dont think it is a good solution ... The best is from the Client side which was a failure because even if the data is not sent to the server, the bytes will be writen too ...

Comment: It depends on size of your upload. If your upload size is too big, then you should do it at server side and make request every second to know the progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could use method

```
write(byte[] b, int off, int len);
```

and calculate percentage according to `offset` variable.

Comment: This method writes to the output stream but does not flush. I tried it but the response will not go to the server until all the bytes are writen...